# Do you distinguish "My cover keeps coming off/undone/untucked"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I have a bed cover but that cover has no buttons. The only way to secure the cover on the bed is to tuck it under the mattress. That is not effective.

Whenever I lie on my bed and it I turn around a few times, the cover got rumpled and some parts of the cover come off the mattress, But other parts of the cover are still on the mattress.

[A woman on Quora said](https://www.quora.com/You-tuck-your-cover-under-the-mattress-and-lie-on-your-bed-but-some-parts-of-the-cover-come-off-the-mattress-which-happens-several-times-Is-it-correct-to-say-the-cover-keeps-undone-keeps-coming-off-keeps-untucked/answer/Cathy-Woods-5?__filter__=all&__nsrc__=notif_page&__sncid__=49877538555&__snid3__=66803194650)

> My bedcover keeps coming untucked when I lie on the bed.
>
> If it comes off then the bedcover is sliding off the bed onto the
> floor.
>
> A quilt cover can come undone if the buttons come out of the
> buttonholes at the bottom.

Do you distinguish "My cover keeps coming off/undone/untucked" like that woman said?

Comment: Your bedcover _comes untucked_ at the sides, and as a result starts to _slide off_ or _slip off_ when you _turn over_. _Coming undone_ is a general term for something working loose after it has been fixed in position. The sense of buttons coming undone is only relevant if your bedcover is a quilt in a removable cover.

Comment: It's not relevant to your question, but I don't usually see "cover" used like this. We do see "covers," plural, as in "I pulled the covers up to my chin," to mean whatever extra things besides a sheet are added to keep you warm. But to speak of only one of these things, the most generic term is "bedspread," and we can use more specific words like "quilt," "blanket," or "duvet," depending how they're constructed.

Comment: I think when the Quora user speaks of buttons they're describing a duvet. A true quilt doesn't usually have a "cover" on top of it (though it's not a very big mistake to call a duvet a "quilt" in a generic sort of way).

Answer (score 2):

"Coming undone" is the most general.  Something you "do" (fasten, place a certain way, etc.) can become "undone".  Your shoelaces can come undone.  (Or, more specifically, untied.)  Your hair that you braided can come undone.  Buttons, especially, can come undone (which is shorter than saying "unbuttoned").

"Coming untucked" means specifically the tucking-under is what is coming undone.  The edges of the cover are being pulled out from under the mattress by you moving around.  (Usually by rolling around or turning over, I don't think people turn around -- head to the foot end, feet to the head end -- so much.)

"Coming off" means an object that is covering another object is moving off of it, thus uncovering it. So, the cover is coming off the mattress (or the bed) because it is sliding to the floor.  Sometimes you hear "The gloves are coming off now!" meaning someone is taking off their gloves because the real fighting is about to start.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note, none of these by themselves really fully describe your situation if the context hasn't been provided. Your second paragraph of your question describes it well. Sometimes it's hard for one word to do all that!